# WPF ColumnDefinition Auto Width MinWidth Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

As I was writing this I found a solution which I will explain below, but for the sake of an academic exercise I was wondering why my original solution didn't work.

I was trying to setup a 3 column `<Grid>` where the left and right hand columns would auto-size to their content but both have the same width, so the smaller column would expand to match the bigger column. This is what I tried, which seems like it should work:

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="FlagColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=NumberColumn}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="NumberColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FlagColumn}"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="AAAA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="BBBBBBBBBBBBB" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="CCCCCCC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
```

This resulted in the columns auto-sizing but seemingly ignoring the MinWidth binding and just auto sizing to their own content independently.

Just FYI, this is what I ended up doing to make it work:

```
        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Corner"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Corner"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="AAAA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="BBBBBBBBBBBBB" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="CCCCCCC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: First solution works for me too..

Comment: I forgot all about SharedSizeGroups! ‍♂️So much easier to implement too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution does work by initializing(one time).

Widths will be later not updated(if you change Text in TextBlocks) because `ActualWidth` of `ColumnDefinition` neither DependencyProperty nor does notify about the change (you could update bindings in code behind, but this solution is ugly).

So if you bind to the `ActualWidth` of `TextBlock`, then you widths will be adjusted:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="FlagColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tb3}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="NumberColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tb1}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="tb1"  Grid.Column="0" Text="AAAA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="BBBBBBBBBBBBB" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb3" Grid.Column="2" Text="CCCCCCC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Moreover your side columns will not shrink in case text in column will be shorter despite `Auto`-size less than `MinWidth` set from previous values, hence new widths can only grow.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, didn't realize it wasn't a dependency property. Silly me.

Comment: It wasn't working in my case because the widths of the columns is 0 on load and gets updated when some bindings get resolved, so the updated ActualWidth never got seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach works fine. Tested like this and working:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="FlagColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=NumberColumn}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="NumberColumn" Width="Auto" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FlagColumn}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="AAAA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="BBBBBBBBBBBBB" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

126.31 for the first and the third column and 531.38 for the middle one

Comment: The other answer got it - because `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` isn't a dependency property it wasn't updating the binding when it's value changed.